# Video formats with alpha channel

Tags: file-formats

Which non-obscure video formats with semi opacity are there?

I want to create clips with that format to have as overlay of other videos, so the format better has to be supported by main video editing programs.

Comment: What do you mean by semi opacity? Do you mean something like a mask?

Comment: Alpha channel, altering topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by formats you mean codecs. The following are codecs that work in either Quicktime (.mov), AVI, and MXF containers, or as image sequences saved as discrete files.

**Commonly used in the industry:**

- Apple Animation (has been around forever, 8 bit support only)
- Apple ProRes 4444 (probably the most widely used? I have no data, just guessing)
- Avid DNxHD & DNxHR (this could be just as widely used)
- GoPro Cineform
- PNG Sequence With Alpha (my favourite, allows for faster [multi-instance renders](https://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/finally-managed-to-peg-my-cpu/)), also TIFF sequences (ditto, but bigger files)

**More obscure:**

- Avid Meridien
- other image sequences: Cineon DPX, Maya IFF, OpenEXR, Targa